# FilterInputStream IS-A InputStream and HAS-A InputStream

Tags: java, libraries, java-io, filter-input

I am reading the source code of Java I/O lib and noticed that `FilterStream` extends the abstract class `InputStream`  favouring inheritance and also has a `InputStream` as an instance variable favoring composition.Why do we need a IS-A and a HAS-A relationship at the same time with `InputStream` ?

Comment: It's an implementation of the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You'll see the pattern all over the `java.io` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FilterInputStream` "is an" input stream that adds or modifies the behavior of an existing input stream that you need to pass in. For example, its subclass `BufferedInputStream` adds a buffering capability. Since `FilterInputStream` needs to hold on to the stream you pass in, there is also a "has a" relationship.

`FilterInputStream` is an example of the *decorator pattern*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern